# How to empty a list

Tags: stack, lisp, common-lisp

I was trying to figure out the way to empty a list (seen as a stack) in Common Lisp.

I came up with this:

```
(defun emptystack ()
    (dolist (var *stack*) (pop *stack*)))
```

But it generates a warning at compile time (VAR is defined but never used).

Then I thought that it would have been simpler just to do:

```
(setq *stack* nil)
```

But still, I was wondering if there was any way to do it manually like in the first function, but without any unused variable.

Comment: Do note that this doesn't really "empty a list", this (eventually)  assigns nil to the variable.  A non empty list is  a cons, and the empty list is a symbol,and you can't turn a cons into a symbol.

Comment: Just set it to `nil`.  Any intermediate steps are wasteful and unneeded obfuscation.

Comment: Hi @Manuel if any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One can *declare* to *ignore* the *unused* variable:

```
(defun emptystack ()
  (dolist (var *stack*)
    (declare (ignore var))
    (pop *stack*)))
```

With the `DO` macro:

```
(defun emptystack ()
  (do ()                ; no bindings
      ((null *stack*))  ; end test, no further results
    (pop *stack*)))     ; body
```

In `LOOP` one can also ignore the variable by naming it `nil`:

```
(defun emptystack ()
  (loop for nil in *stack* do (pop *stack*)))
```

Comment: Interestingly this (DOLIST) doesn't work in Clozure CL, but works well in SBCL.

Comment: I think it's implementation dependent whether one can destructively modify a list inside `dolist`. I think `(loop while *stack*...)` or `(dotimes (i length *stack*)...)` is the safest option. At least in SBCL `dotimes` does not complain about unused variable.

Comment: The Clozure CL problem looks more like a bug there.

Answer (score 5):

You could use

```
(defun emptystack ()
  (loop while *stack* do (pop *stack*)))
```

which indeed does not use a variable under the hood:

```
? (macroexpand-1 '(loop while *stack* do (pop *stack*)))
(BLOCK NIL (ANSI-LOOP::LOOP-BODY NIL ((UNLESS *STACK* (GO ANSI-LOOP::END-LOOP))) ((POP *STACK*)) ((UNLESS *STACK* (GO ANSI-LOOP::END-LOOP))) NIL))
```